# About the effect of parallelism in StormCrawler

Tags: apache-storm, stormcrawler, apache-storm-configs

I am currently working on a Storm Crawler based project. We have a fixed and limited amount of bandwidth for fetching page from the web. We have 8 worker with a large value for parallelism hint for different Bolt in the topology (i.e. 50). So lots of thread created for fetching the page. Is there any relation between increasing number of fetch_error and increasing parallelism_hint in the project? How can I determine the good value for the parallelism_hint in the Storm Crawler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parallelism hint is not something that should be applied to all bolts indiscriminately.

Ideally, you need one instance of FetcherBolt per worker, so in your case 8. As you've probably read in the [WIKI](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/FetcherBolt%28s%29) or seen in the conf, the FetcherBolt handles internal threads for fetching. This is determined by the config *fetcher.threads.number* which is set to 50 in the archetypes' configurations (assuming this is what you used as a starting point).

Using too many FetcherBolt instances is counterproductive. It is better to change the value of *fetcher.threads.number* instead. If you have 50 Fetcher instances with a default number of threads of 50, that would give you 2500 fetching threads which might be too much for your available bandwidth.

As I mentioned before you want 1 FetcherBolt per worker, the number of internal fetching threads per bolt depends on your bandwidth. There is no hard rule for this, it depends on your situation.

One constant I have observed however is the ratio of parsing bolts to Fetcher bolts; usually, 4 parsers per fetcher works fine. Run Storm in deployed mode and check the *capacity* value for the parser bolts in the UI. If the value is 1 or above, try using more instances and see if it affects the capacity.

In any case, not all bolts need the same level of parallelism.